# Removing an element from BST (pointer error)

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have my own implementation on BST. Now I need to implement `remove_value` function, which would remove a node with that value from my tree. I have this simple code:

```
void binary_tree::remove_value(int value)
{
    if (!this->exists(value)) return; //if value doesnt exist - return
    nodeBST* current = root;
    nodeBST* prev = nullptr;
    bool left = true;
    while (true)
    {
        if (current->value == value) // when we find it
        {
            if (current->right == nullptr && current->left == nullptr) // 0 children
            {   
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                if (left) prev->left = nullptr;
                else prev->right = nullptr;
                //even tried delete current here
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right == nullptr && current->left != nullptr) // 1 lewe dziecko
            {
                if (left) prev->left == current->left;
                else prev->right == current->left;
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right != nullptr && current->left == nullptr) // 1 prawe dziecko dziecko
            {
                if (left) prev->left == current->right;
                else prev->right == current->right;
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right != nullptr && current->left != nullptr) // dwoje dzieci
            {
                nodeBST* tempNode = findMin(current);
                current->value = tempNode->value;
                remove_node(current, prev, left);
            }
        }
        else if (current->value > value)
        {
            prev = current;
            left = true;
            current = current->left;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = current;
            left = false;
            current = current->right;
        }
    }
}
```

I know its kinda mess, so I will tell you what it does. The bottom part is looping through the tree. If the the value we are searching is bigger that the current node value, the `previous becomes current`, `current becomes current->right` and `left = false`. The opposite, when its smaller. Now look that the first `if` after `current->value == value` - this is the code which should execute for 0 children. Now, it does delete the current node, but I have a problem.

I have a printing function, which takes a whole tree, and prints it. And it crashes with some pointer error. I checked. When I `delete current` it sets `prev->left` or `prev->right` (depending on `left` value) to like `0xdddddddd`, no matter if I delete after assigning `prev->` or before. I even tried to `delete prev->right/left` and then assign `nullptr` but still the same happens. How can I make it delete the node, but still be able to assign `nullptr` to `right` or `left` property of `prev` node?

@Edit:

This code fails on line with `print(`:

```
void binary_tree::print(std::string sp, std::string sn, nodeBST* v)
{
    if (this->is_empty()) return;
    std::string s;
    if (v)
    {
        s = sp;
        if (sn == cr) s[s.length() - 2] = ' ';
        print(s + cp, cr, v->right);

        s = s.substr(0, sp.length() - 2);
        std::cout << s << sn << v->value << std::endl;

        s = sp;
        if (sn == cl) s[s.length() - 2] = ' ';
        print(s + cp, cl, v->left);
    }
}
```

The exception is something like (I am translating from my language) that there was unwanted read from memory, and that the `v was 0xddddd`

Comment: First of all try to *unmess* the code. Simple, easy to read code is also code that is easy to maintain and check for problems. Then use a debugger to find out where in your code the crash happens (not having multiple statements on a single line helps), and also to check the values of all involved variables. If you still can't figure it out then please edit your question to tell *us* the details (location and variable values).

Comment: I know there it does. My printing function uses `node->right` or `node->left` and then Visual Studio starts to yell

Comment: Furthermore, if you read e.g. [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260966%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) you will see that `0xdddddddd` is a special value Visual C++ and its debugger uses for memory that has been free'd. That means you are using memory that you have deleted previously. That in turn *probably* means you do not unlink nodes from the tree properly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, exactly as I thought. And I would like you ask you how can I unlink nodes properly

Comment: `I know its kinda mess, ...` If it's so messy that you think you have to explain it's working to us, how can you possibly expect **anyone** to be able to help you with your problem? And how are you going to  solve any issues that arise, say, next month, when you don't really remember what you have written. There's only one real solution: **Write. Clean. Code.** Or try to, at the very least. Don't be sloppy when it comes to code quality.

Comment: @Frynio Did you test this code to attempt to delete a tree with a single node?  It sure looks crash-worthy for the simplest of examples, since `prev` is being dereferenced before actually being set to anything (besides `nullptr`).

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` notation to access class data members or methods.

Comment: Not exactly. I use it when I have two same variable names, like `this->n` and `n`

Comment: @Frynio It would help a lot if you named your variables a little better than single letters.  Using single letter variable names puts you in danger of inadvertently declaring a local variable with the same name, thus hiding the name you really want to be using.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I actually figured out where is the problem. Like its the most obvious one XD I do `prev->left == current->left` instead of `=`. Jesus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was a bug inside `if (current->right == nullptr && current->left == nullptr)`. This code is working:

```
void binary_tree::remove_value(int value)
{
    if (!this->exists(value)) return; //if value doesnt exist - return
    nodeBST* current = root;
    nodeBST* prev = nullptr;
    bool left = true;
    while (true)
    {
        if (current->value == value) // when we find it
        {
            if (current->right == nullptr && current->left == nullptr) // 0 children
            {   
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                if(prev!=nullptr) {
                if (left) prev->left = nullptr;
                else prev->right = nullptr;
                }
                //even tried delete current here
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right == nullptr && current->left != nullptr) // 1 lewe dziecko
            {
                if(prev!=nullptr) {
                if (left) prev->left == current->left;
                else prev->right == current->left;}
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right != nullptr && current->left == nullptr) // 1 prawe dziecko dziecko
            {
                if(prev!=nullptr) {
                if (left) prev->left == current->right;
                else prev->right == current->right;}
                delete current;
                this->n--;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->right != nullptr && current->left != nullptr) // dwoje dzieci
            {
                nodeBST* tempNode = findMin(current);
                current->value = tempNode->value;
                remove_node(current, prev, left);
            }
        }
        else if (current->value > value)
        {
            prev = current;
            left = true;
            current = current->left;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = current;
            left = false;
            current = current->right;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work for 1 or more children, but I will find out whats wrong :D

Comment: i made an edit a while ago, did you update the code?

Comment: look inside else if (current->right != nullptr && current->left == nullptr)

Comment: Yes I did :D But still `0xddddddd` problem

Comment: I know, right. I tried to copy f.e  `current->left` to a temporary variable, then `delete current` and then everything else (`prev->left/right = temp`), but still the same

Comment: give me a example where this code fails and excatly what error you get

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: From the debugger I can see, that when it wants to reassign `prev->left/right` to `temp` (`temp = current->left/right`) it cannot do it, cuz I've deleted the current. I don't really know how can I make the pointer survive

Comment: When delete current exactly?